# Tensorflow: Incredibly Huge Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a text classification task in Tensorflow (with `tf.keras`).  Previously, I was just using text features, my loss was `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, and training looked like this:

[image]

This is totally expected and the loss is ~7.

Now, I'm adding in 2 random float features that are between 0 and 100,000.  I've updated my `tf.data.Dataset` objects so they now look something like:

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"review": x_rev_train, "structured": x_structured_train}, labels_train))`

and have created a new `Input` object, connected it to my graph.  Seems normal.

I train now and see this:
[image]

So my loss is now on the order of 10s of millions (it starts off above 100mm).  I'm very confused by this.  Given how categorical cross-entropy is defined, this seems obviously wrong...

So I set about debugging and made the two float features a constant value of 0.0.  When I do that, the loss goes back to being as in the first image.

Then I set both float features to a constant value of 100000.0 and the problem returns.  So I think it somehow has to do with the size of those two float features.

Any thoughts about what I might be doing incorrectly?  I understand I haven't scaled these two float features, but why would my loss blow up like that?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Edit:

It appears this massive loss only occurs on the first epoch somehow?  It goes back to normal for subsequent epochs.  Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: How many classes do you have? Could you provide more details about your model?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you need to normalise your numerical features in the model. This is necessary in virtually all ANNs that have features with different ranges of values that can be taken. After the first step the weights can make a huge jump to try to model those large-scale features and your loss will return to normal, but at the start the weights are random and probably centred around zero, depending on how you initialise them. If you think of what the output predictions would be for those small feature weights at the very start and then see the difference is going to be on the order of millions for those unnormalised feature values, this is why the loss value blows up.

The lesson is you should have never put those features into the network without normalising them first (subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation). Try doing that and you will see that the behaviour will return to normal.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it expected that accuracy is still degraded after the loss returns to a normal level?  I normally see around 6x the accuracy I'm seeing right now with the 2 very large features (and it doesn't improve after the first epoch).